# Laravel MIME validation not working with .doc file

Tags: php, laravel, validation

The validation form works successfully with another extension but does not work with `.doc`.

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('documents.store') }}" class="needs-validation" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <label for="document" class="form-label">
        File <strong class="text-azul">(Files accepteds: PDF,WORD,JPG,PNG)</strong>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="document" name="document" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.png,.jpg" required>
    <x-jet-button>{{ __('Save') }}</x-jet-button>
</form>
```

In the controller:

```php
$request->validate([
    'document' => 'file|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,png,jpg,jpeg',
]);
```

On select file with extension `.doc`, it returns:

> The document must be a file of type: doc, docx, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg.

Comment: I am not sure what is the final MIME Laravel reads. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#basic-usage-of-mime-rule). Your MIMEs should be okay, just to test, exactly before the validation do `dd($request->file('document'));` so we can see the file information, including it's MIME.

Comment: My problem was a corrupt document.I tried a new doc and it works. Mimetypes was not working with the corrupt document. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimetypes) you can also validate the mime types:

```php
$request->validate([
    'document' => 'mimetypes:application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
]);
```

The example above should allow only the types *doc* and *docx* (you can add as many as you need).

Please find the common mime types in the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: But i prefer to use mimes, specifying file extensions. My problem was a corrupt document.I tried a new doc and it works. Mimetypes was not working with the corrupt document.

Comment: So do you allow the upload of corrupted files? Maybe you can use both validations (mimes and mimetypes) so you get a double benefit :)

Comment: It does not allow the upload of the corrupt file, which is why I asked the question, mimes and mimetypes works correctly.